# Assigning a Character an Integer Value for a Map using a 'For Loop'

Tags: java, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I'm trying to make an easy way to assign all the letter a value using a map. I have tried using a for loop however when I try and get the value for an of the letters, I receive null.

```
import java.util.*;

/*
* This class scores words in the game of Scrabble.
* A word's score is the total of its individual tile scores.
*/

    public class ScrabbleScorer {
        private final Map<Character, Integer> tileScores;

        public ScrabbleScorer() {
        char[] tiles = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();

        // TODO: initialise the array of individual letter scores
        int[] scores = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

        // TODO: create the `tileScores` map
        tileScores = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        // TODO: populate the `tileScores` map using the `tiles`
        // and `scores` arrays

        for(int i=0; i<scores.length; i++){
              tileScores.put(tiles[i],scores[i]);
        };

        System.out.println(tileScores.get("A"));       
}
```

Comment: `"A"` is a `String`, not a `Character`. You need to write `'A'` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Map` contains `Character` keys, not `String` keys. Change this

```
System.out.println(tileScores.get("A"));
```

to

```
System.out.println(tileScores.get('A'));
```

Comment: Thank you, very silly mistake... Still getting used to the basics.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really looking for an easy way to bind scores to letters, I recommend you to take advantage of the fact that the letter set is **sequentially ordered**, so the letters may be used to **index** the scores array (remember that a `char` is a *numeric* type):

```
public int getScoreForLetter(char letter)
{
    return scores[letter-'A'];
}
```